# How to extract pages from "2-pages-per-sheet" PDF?

Tags: pdf

I have a ("horizontally") scanned book with 2-pages-per-sheet. It's very hard to read on an ebook reader. I would like to extract every page from every sheet and create "normal" PDF file, containing 1-page-per-sheet. How can I do it?

Comment: Using which programming language and pdf library do you want to implement that task?

Comment: Whatever. Bash script + unix tools would be the best.

Comment: PDF Scissors - https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/